# problem with adding the column Datetime to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe ready to be used in different models. like below
[image: dataframe]

Now I want to add another column to this data frame known as "Date time". The column seems ok before adding it.
[image: date time column]

When I try to add this column to the dataframe through this line `df1['date'] = date` it shows that there are **NaN** in the column which is wrong because I have checked and there is not NaN in that. I did "reset index" but again faced the same issue.
[image: DF with NAN]

Comment: The index for your date list starts at 2, this means that for index 0 and 1 there is no value. That is why when you merge the date column into your dataframe the first two rows have NaN for the date column

Comment: You have a column named “index” rather than just having the index. The column “index” misses 2 two entries (0 and 1) and thus in your end df, the records on index 0 and 1 are empty (or, NaN)

Answer (score 1):

Your index column starts from 2 that means first 2 indices are missing,

First reset your index by using `df.reset_index()` see the code line below

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then try your code line `df1['date'] = date`

Answer (score 0):

try, It might help:

```
df1['date'] = date['datecolumname']
```

The add time cannot see it as a single column, which causes an error, there must be 1 column.Correct the date base.